# Problems while designing a database to manage all kind of products like Amazon

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, relational-database, database-normalization

first of all sorry for my bad english hehehe I need some help, I want to design a database for a website, like a mini Amazon. This database will manage every kind of products (TV, cars, computers, books, videogames, penciles, tables, pants...), but also, each product must have some properties (that will be indexed) for example, if the product is a book, the properties will be something like genre, year, author. If the product is a TV, the properties will be something like size, color, also year. And if the product is a car, the properties will be something like year, color, model, for example. So, this is my idea:

1. One table to manage departments (like electronics, books...)
2. One table to manage categories of the departments, this table will be a child of the previous. If the department is electronics, here will be audio, tv and video, games... (each category belongs to one department, the relationship is one department to many categories)
3. One table to manage the products (each product belongs to one category, the relationship is one category to many products)
4. One table to manage properties (like year, color, genre, model...)
5. One table to engage products with properties, this table will be called ProductProperties

Im not sure if this is the best way, the database will be huge, I will develop the database on MySQL. But, I think this is not the best way, this article talks about "Database Abstraction: Aggregation and Generalization" http://cs-exhibitions.uni-klu.ac.at/index.php?id=433, in other words generic objects (I think), but this way is old (70s). In this article http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/ in the section "One table to hold all domain values" says that this is a wrong way... Im saying all of this because of the table ProductProperties, I dont know if I make this table or if I make especific tables for each kind of products.

Do you have any suggestion? Or do you have a better idea?

Thanks in advance, take care!!!

Answer (score 2):

> 1.One table to manage departments (like electronics, books...)
>   2.One table to manage categories of the departments, this table will be a
>   child of the previous. If the
>   department is electronics, here will
>   be audio, tv and video, games... (each
>   category belongs to one department,
>   the relationship is one department to
>   many categories)

Why? One table, categories, forming a hierarchy. More flexible.

> 3.One table to manage the products (each product belongs to one category,
>   the relationship is one category to
>   many products)

Why? Allow m:n here. A product in many categorries.

> Im not sure if this is the best way,
>   the database will be huge

Ah - no. Sorry. Nontrivial, yes. Hugh? No. Just to get you an idea of hugh - I have a db I am adding 1.2 billion rows PER DAY to a specific table. On average. THIS is big. YOu end up with what - 100.000 items? not even worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo89, the description of what you want is very close to what the AdventureWorks database for SQL Server does.  There are many examples of using AdventureWorks on the Web from web applicatons to reporting to BI.

Download and install SQL Server Express 2008 R2.  Download and install the sample database for the above product.  Inspect the database design for AdventureWorks.

Use AdventureWorks as examples in questions you may post.

I use AdventureWorks because I use SQL Server.  I do not say it is better than other database products I say this because I know AdventureWorks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that some database can work fast with 500,000,000 items. Complete tree of products categories for amazon.com contains 51,000 nodes ([amazoncategories.info](http://amazoncategories.info/)). Also the data is updated hourly, so saved product information can be incorrect. I think the optimal way is to store categories tree only get the product data at runtime using Amazon's API.